# how to open a app when its in quit state while receiving fcm push notification - REACT NATIVE

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, facebook, firebase-cloud-messaging

Planning to build an app like uber we have two apps one for end users other for drivers, if end users send a booking notification we need to display in driver app push notification as 'cancel' and 'accept' button  with sound like ringtone or we need to open the app automatically, if the app is in quit state or background state. Technologies used: - react native, firebase. Please help me to resolve and am eagerly waiting for your valuable suggestions and ideas

Answer (score 1):

https://0x1bitcrack3r.medium.com/incoming-call-notifications-for-react-native-apps-ef4725702401 - using this blog i can able to change the push notification ui and able to trigger ringtone like whats app call

Comment: Thanks but the FCM right now is updated, it's really hard for me to set up, did you know some article tutorial to set up "how to open a app when its in quit state while receiving fcm push notification ", thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
      navigation.navigate('TransactionWithNotification', remoteMessage);
    });

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
          navigation.navigate('TransactionWithNotification', remoteMessage);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      });

    messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Notification foregorund state:', remoteMessage);
      navigation.navigate('TransactionWithNotification', remoteMessage);
    });
  }, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest you to go for  https://rnfirebase.io/ using this you can have an node app or use firebase function to push notification to the device which is registered
here you would use the following

onNotificationOpenedApp
:
When the user presses a notification displayed via FCM, this listener will be called if the app has opened from a background state.https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging

```
onNotificationOpenedApp(listener: (message: RemoteMessage) => any): () => void;
```

Comment: Thanks, but we need a scenario like while receiving notification open the app automatically without notification click by user, for this do we have any solution????

Comment: Hi! @KarthikCS did you found the solution?